# Two identical application different cpu usages behavior

Tags: linux, cpu, top, application, load

I have two openstack instance

node1 - 16 vCPU / 16GB memory 
node2 - 8 vCPU / 8GB memory

both machine behind F5 load-balancer (round-robin) and running `MongoosIM` application, but i am noticing that 16 vCPU core machine cpu utilization is always high than low cpu cloud node, why?

node 1

```
top - 04:08:00 up 113 days, 10:50,  1 user,  load average: 5.78, 5.78, 5.73
Tasks: 215 total,   1 running, 214 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  7.5 us,  4.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 86.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.1 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu1  :  7.6 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu2  : 32.0 us, 18.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 46.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.2 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu3  : 32.3 us, 19.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 46.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.9 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu4  : 13.3 us,  6.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 80.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu5  :  4.1 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu6  : 42.4 us, 23.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 29.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  4.0 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu7  : 40.2 us, 24.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 31.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  4.1 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu8  :  7.5 us,  3.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 88.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu9  :  3.4 us,  2.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu10 : 42.3 us, 25.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 27.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  3.6 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu11 : 42.0 us, 24.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 29.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  3.7 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu12 : 10.8 us,  5.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu13 :  5.5 us,  3.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 90.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu14 : 38.6 us, 18.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 40.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.5 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu15 : 36.7 us, 21.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 39.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.2 si,  0.7 st
KiB Mem : 16265260 total, 10171104 free,  4512244 used,  1581912 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  3299368 free,   894932 used. 11295924 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
24196 mongoos+  20   0 6133060   4.0g   5356 S 634.2 25.8   2008:49 beam.smp
15607 root      20   0  369660   4332   2200 S   3.0  0.0  16:15.21 syslog-ng
28638 telegraf  20   0 1467376  10920   2572 S   1.0  0.1  66:32.90 telegraf
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0 220:19.68 rcu_sched
   24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   1:18.90 ksoftirqd/3
    1 root      20   0  191916   2852   1632 S   0.0  0.0  50:34.00 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:07.09 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:46.54 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:08.29 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lru-add-drain
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:38.17 watchdog/0
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:34.54 watchdog/1
   13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:26.85 migration/1
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:36.04 ksoftirqd/1
```

node 2

```
top - 04:08:03 up 11 days,  8:44,  1 user,  load average: 4.85, 5.19, 5.32
Tasks: 157 total,   1 running, 156 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 33.7 us, 10.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 54.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu1  : 30.1 us,  9.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  0.7 st
%Cpu2  : 50.4 us, 21.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 11.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi, 16.2 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 56.8 us, 25.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 17.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.4 st
%Cpu4  : 28.4 us,  9.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.7 si,  2.6 st
%Cpu5  : 26.5 us, 10.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 60.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  2.6 st
%Cpu6  : 32.1 us,  8.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  1.5 st
%Cpu7  : 26.8 us,  9.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 62.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  1.1 st
KiB Mem :  8009896 total,   380252 free,  4294772 used,  3334872 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  3085036 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
17526 mongoos+  20   0 5134916 3.715g   5364 S 406.3 48.6   1496:28 beam.smp
 1640 root      20   0  567508   7544   1924 S   3.0  0.1 408:19.27 syslog-ng
 3669 tcpdump   20   0   32404   9316   7964 S   2.3  0.1 471:10.66 tcpdump
  544 dbus      20   0   70440   1244    620 S   0.7  0.0   4:14.68 dbus-daemon
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0  67:35.00 rcu_sched
  417 root      20   0   39476   3628   3228 S   0.3  0.0   1:16.69 systemd-journal
  907 root      20   0  523728   5724   2988 S   0.3  0.1   0:33.15 rsyslogd
    1 root      20   0   43856   3024   1296 S   0.0  0.0   3:26.52 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.37 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:48.60 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.63 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.42 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.02 watchdog/1
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.75 migration/1
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:29.87 ksoftirqd/1
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
   16 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.04 watchdog/2
   17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.58 migration/2
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  11:16.55 ksoftirqd/2
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H
   21 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:03.88 watchdog/3
   22 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.89 migration/3
```